# Let $K$ be a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. View $K$ as a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$. If $\sigma$ is complex conjugation, show that $\sigma(K) = K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

**Let $K$ be a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. View $K$ as a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$. If $\sigma$ is complex conjugation, show that $\sigma(K) = K$, so $\sigma|_K\in \text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$. Show that $F(\sigma|_K) = K\cap \mathbb{R}$, and conclude that $[K:K\cap \mathbb{R}]\leq 2$. Give examples to show that both $[K:K\cap \mathbb{R}]= 1$ and $[K:K\cap \mathbb{R}]= 2$ can occur.**

I am very confused solving this problem. How many subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ are there that are an extension of Gaois of $\mathbb{Q}$? If $a\in K$ then I can say that $\text{Im}(a)=0$ and thus conclude that $\sigma(a)=a$? To show $F(\sigma|_K) = K\cap \mathbb{R}$, I think I can try the inclusion $"\supseteq" $, but the other inclusion I do not know how to prove it, could you please help me? I can say that $|\text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})|\leq 2$ for being $K$ a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ and so $[K:K\cap \mathbb{R}]\leq 2$ ?. How can I find such examples? Thank you very much.

Comment: If $K \not\subset \mathbb{R}$, the main point is with $\sigma$ the complex conjugaison, $H = \{1, \sigma\}$ is a finite subgroup of $\text{Aut}(K)$. With the fixed field $K^H = \{a \in K, \forall g \in H, g(a) = a\} = \{ a \in K, \sigma(a) = a\} = K \cap \mathbb{R}$ then $K/K^H$ is a Galois extension with Galois group $H$, thus $[K:K^H] = |H|=  2$. If $K \subset \mathbb{R}$, the same holds with $H = \{1\}$ the trivial subgroup.

Comment: I think you're a bit confused about the notation: $\sigma(K)=K$ means $\sigma(K)\subset K$ and $K\subset \sigma(K)$. Does not means $\sigma|_K=\operatorname{id}_K$.

Comment: If $K$ is a galois extension then from the definition of Galois extension it is normal. So if $\sigma$ is the complex conjugation for a root $\alpha\in K$ of a polynomial $f$, then $\overline{\alpha}$ is also a root of this polynomial and hence is in $K$. To see the reason that if $\alpha$ is a root then so does $\overline{\alpha}$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2130424/if-an-polynomial-has-a-complex-root-is-it-necessary-that-its-conjugate-is-also