# Find $a\in \mathbb{R}$ such that a root of $ax^3-13x^2+(15a)x-25$ is $2+i$

Tags: linear-algebra

Find $a\in \mathbb{R}$ such that a root of the polynomial $$p(x)=ax^3-13x^2+(15a)x-25$$ is $2+i$

Solution:

$q(x)=\frac{p(x)}{a}$

$=x^3-\frac{13}{a}x^2+15x-\frac{25}{a}$

$p(x)$ and $q(x)$ have the same roots, call them $r_1, r_2, r_3$

$r_1=2+i$. Since the coefficients are all real we know $r_2=2-i$

$(x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3)= x^3-(r_1+r_2+r_3)x^2+(r_1r_2 + r_1r_3 +r_2r_3)x-r_1r_2r_3$

$r_1+r_2+r_3=\frac{13}{a}$

$(2+i)(2-i)+r_3=\frac{13}{a}$

$5+r_3=\frac{13}{a}$

We also have:
$r_1r_2r_3=\frac{25}{a}$

$(2+i)(2-i)r_3=\frac{25}{a}$

$5r_3=\frac{25}{a}$

$r_3=\frac{5}{a}$

Going back to $5+r_3=\frac{13}{a}$

We have $5+\frac{5}{a}=\frac{13}{a}$

Thus $a=\frac{8}{5}$

The statement I am having trouble with is
"$r_1=2+i$. Since the coefficients are all real we know $r_2=2-i$"

Why do we know what $r_2$ is? I understand it's the conjugate and that $r_1r_2=5$ is a real number. But I don't understand why the coefficients being real implies that $r_2=2-i$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If an polynomial has a complex root, is it necessary that its conjugate is also a root?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2130424/if-an-polynomial-has-a-complex-root-is-it-necessary-that-its-conjugate-is-also)

Comment: that is helpful, thank you! does this mean that if the two roots and conjugate imaginary pairs, then the third root has to be a real number? or can the third root also be a complex number?

Comment: Strange. Why don't you just substitute $2+i$ for $x$ and solve for $a$? You cannot divide by $a$, by the way, if you do not know that $a\ne 0$.

Comment: The answer is $a=2$.

Comment: I tried your method of substituting $2+i$ and I get $32(a-1)+26(a-2)i=0$ Not sure what to do from here @markvs

Comment: Yes, the third root must be real. More generally, any odd degree polynomial with real coefficients has at least one real root.

Comment: @user8290579: Your computation is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Plug in $2+i$ into $p(x)$. Note that $(2+i)^2=3+4i$, $(2+i)^3=2+11i$. So $$p(2+i)= a*(2+11i) -13*(3+4i)+15a*(2+i)-25=
(32a-64)+(26a-52)i =(a-2)(32+26i)=0.$$ So $a=2$.This is much easier than what is in the OP and gives the right result. You do not need the assumption that $a$ is real.

Answer (score 0):

The coefficients of the polynomial is real, hence complex roots comes in conjugate pairs.

If $$\sum_{i=0}^n a_i z^i = 0$$

We can take conjugate and see that

$$\sum_{i=0}^n a_i \bar{z}^i = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

$(x-2)^2 = -1 $ or $x^2 - 4x + 5 = 0$ represents the pair of complex roots.

$$\begin {aligned}
p(x) &=ax^3-13x^2+(15a)x-25 \\
& = (ax^3 - 4ax^2 + 5ax) - ((13-4a) x^2 - 10ax + 25) \\
& = ax (x^2 - 4x + 5) - 5 \left(\frac{13-4a}{5} x^2 - 2ax + 5 \right)
\end{aligned}$$

That gives $a = 2$ as the solution.